# How to select two extensions of images with css3?

Tags: jquery, css, css-selectors, attributes

I've this code

```
    jQuery.each(jQuery('img[src$="jpg"]'), function (index, image) {
      if (jQuery(image).width() >= min_width && jQuery(image).height() >= min_height) {
        image_url = jQuery(image).attr('src');
        jQuery('#bookmarklet .images').append('<a href="#"><img src="' + image_url + '" /></a>');

      }
    });
```

In the first line `img[src$="jpg"]` selects all the images with the extension **.jpg** but I also want to add the extension **.png**. I've tried this `img[src$="jpg"][src$="png"]` but it produces error. So is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
img[src$="jpg"],[src$="png"] {
  /* ... */
}
```